# How to personalise Win7Pro recycling bin icons so that refreshing cache is not needed when the bin is emptied or a file is put into it?

Tags: windows-7, icons

On Windows 7 Pro I have changed both icons for the recycling bin (full and empty) to ones I prefer. But when the bin is empty and I put a file in it, the icon only changes to the one for a full bin when I refresh the cache by pressing F5. Similarly when the bin is full and I empty it, I also need to refresh the cache to get the icon to change to the one for an empty bin.

How can I get the icon to change as soon as I put a file into a previously empty bin and as soon as I empty a bin that was not previously empty?

Comment: Does someone here know?

Comment: Clearly not. Can people recommend another site where people might know?